# does updating cloudwatch agent in linux instances affect existing metrics/cloudwatch dashboards?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, redhat

I got many red hat linux instances in aws . configured many custom cloudwatch metrics and cloudwatch dashbaords are working fine.

now am planning to update cloudwatch agent in all linux instances to latest version.. if i do so, will it affect any of my custom metrics/dashboards ? ?
or is it gonna work as normal after updates ?